# Custom SSL Authority NSStream swift

Tags: objective-c, security, swift, osx-yosemite, nsstream

Key points:

Client: Swift with NSStream looped event

Server: Python twisted custom protocol

Currently to connect to my server, i need to import my SSL signing authority into the apple key chain along with the public key.

i want to bypass all of the importing process so that my application loads my signing authority and public key so anyone can use it without having to import new items into their key chain. What are my options if any?

Here is my current stream connection function.

```
func connect() {

    println("Attempting to Connect To Server")

    //Create Stream
    NSStream.getStreamsToHostWithName(serverAddress, port: serverPort, inputStream: &readStream, outputStream: &writeStream)

    //Set read/write delegates
    readStream?.delegate = self
    writeStream?.delegate = self

    //Set SSL
    readStream?.setProperty(NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelNegotiatedSSL, forKey: NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelKey)
    writeStream?.setProperty(NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelNegotiatedSSL, forKey: NSStreamSocketSecurityLevelKey)

    //Set streams into run loops
    self.readStream?.scheduleInRunLoop(NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop(), forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)
    self.writeStream?.scheduleInRunLoop(NSRunLoop.currentRunLoop(), forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)

    //Open Streams
    self.readStream?.open()
    self.writeStream?.open()
}
```

Comment: Is the cert self-signed or signed by a CA that is in the Keychain System Roots?

Comment: self signed then imported

Comment: Allowing one app to add a cert that other apps can use is a security violation, there is no trust to a verified signer. Why not get your cert signed by a CA that is in Keychain System Roots?

Comment: it is a personal project that i am not planing on publishing so i do not want to spend the money. Also i do not want other apps to use it just my app so it can connect to my server through ssl